# How is it possible that when installing requirements I get the following error?

Tags: php, composer-php

https://github.com/php-twinfield/twinfield/blob/master/readme.md

I'm trying to install the top requirements by running the following command from cmd:

```
composer require 'php-twinfield/twinfield:^3.0'
```

however, getting the following error:

```
  [UnexpectedValueException]
  Could not parse version constraint 3.0': Invalid version string "3.0'"
```

Comment: Cannot replicate. What platform are you running this on?

Comment: Looks like it took the trailing single quote to be part of the value, instead of seeing it as a delimiter? Try without the quotes, they should not be needed here.

Comment: Maybe a problem with your shell? You could try double quotes instead: composer require "php-twinfield/twinfield:^3.0"

Comment: This seems to be platfofm/shell dependant. As the command on the question, exactly as typed, works for other users. Without more information is impossible to guess, but try different variations without quotes, with different types of quotes, etc.

Comment: w/o quotes I'm getting the following error Root package 'php-twinfield/twinfield' cannot require itself in its composer.json

Comment: I'm sorry for asking dumb questions :(

Comment: Would `composer require php-twinfield/twinfield "^3.0"` work? Also, "cannot require itself" sounds strange - can you share the current state of `composer.json` in the directory you are calling that command from, along with some more details about your setup (versions of Composer and PHP, which OS)?

Comment: @NicoHaase Thank you for your response
 OS = Windows 10,
 Composer version 2.1.6 2021-08-19 17:11:08,
PHP 8.0.9 (cli) (built: Jul 29 2021 14:12:19) ( ZTS Visual C++ 2019 x64 )
composer.json will follow below

Comment: I'm sorry what can I do to show you the current state?

Comment: I think it worked with powershell as admin and going one directory back. I had to enable soap extension in php.ini

Comment: Please edit your question to contain all relevant information